# to find the frequency of words in a text file using java

Tags: hashset

Ive managed to parse the entire contents of a given input text file and store each word in a hash set. But now i need to find the frequenct of each of these words in this input file, any suggestions as to how I can go about? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `HashMap` instead of a `HashSet` and this class as the value:

```
class Counter {
    public int frequency;
}
```

`addWord()` then looks like this:

```
public void addWord (String word) {
    Counter c = map.get (word);
    if (c == null) {
        c = new Counter ();
        map.put(word, c);
    }
    c.frequency ++;
}
```

Comment: You could just do Map<String, Integer> and avoid the intermediate class.

Comment: Thanks! Now the next problem is how do i print the entire thing.. i need to print each word with its corresponding fruquency..

Comment: for(Entry<String, Integer> e : map) System.out.println(e.getValue + " " + e.getKey())

Comment: I think il listen to Jon and read through the documents! how different is this from a hashset?

Comment: You might want to dig out the old comp sci textbook and have a look at the differences between List/Set/Map

Comment: A set is a collection of values, a map is a collection of keys plus one value per key.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help.. it worked out.. and to print it in a separate file( needed the op in tat form) copied the frequency and the word into 2 separate lists and printing that.. works.. but anything more efficient?

Comment: @Nanda: Use `for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()) { System.out.println(entry.getKey()+": "+entry.getValue()+" times"; }`.